# Stick a div to the bottom of a table-cell div

Tags: css, alignment, css-tables

I have a 3 cols layout using display table-cell.

```
<div id=left>
  LONG Left menu
</div>
<div id=content>
  Some text content
  <div id=toolbar></div>
</div>
<div id=right>
  LONG Right menu
</div>
```

Is it possible to stick the toolbar to the bottom of the content div also with LONG left and right menu? I have tried setting the position to absolute and bottom:0 but it behaves differently in the different browsers.

Any idea?

SOLUTION:

I found a solution that works with ie,ff,chrome. Putting a wrapper div and setting the height of the container table to 0px solved the problem.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bunobici/1/edit)

Comment: This seems to be a css question, but I don't see any CSS. Can you post your CSS or set up a jsfiddle to replicate the issue?

Comment: Hard to answer with just html. I recommend you try bootstrap. They make these kinds of things pretty easy and has really good documentation.

Comment: Try this with chrome and firefox: http://jsbin.com/qudotuyo/1/edit

Answer (score 3):

This is probably what you are looking for :

You need to set the parent `div` to `position: relative` and the child `div` to `position: absolute` and then set the distance from the sides of the parent div. i.e. `top: 0` sets its position to the bottom of the div. `left: 0` aligns it so that it sticks to the left side of the parent div.

### [Here's the Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q6kYr/)

### HTML

```
<div id="content"> <!--Parent Div-->
  Some text content
  <div id="toolbar"></div> <!--Child Div-->
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#content {
    background: blue;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    position: relative;
}
#toolbar {
    background: grey;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you need:

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/xuwif/1/edit)

```
#content {
  position: relative;
}
#toolbar {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```